# My model doesn't follow my armature, but only in rendered mode (2.8)

Tags: rigging, armature

When I'm in object mode everything tracks correctly, but when switching to rendered view, or rendering outright, the model become off track, and distorted.

Haven't the faintest idea what could be causing this, so any help would be great, thanks.

[image: [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aNG6.png)

Comment: Are all your modifiers (Including Armature) Activated for the viewport and rendered view?

Comment: Yes I have made sure that they are enabled for render.

Comment: maybe share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/